# Start new Activity From BroadcastReceiver or Service Class

Tags: android

Hello have to start a new Activity from the BroascastReceiver or the Service, but I have found error that cant start activity without activity context.

I use the following code

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,MyActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

And also include the activity in Mainifest file,

Please resolve it,

And another second problem is, I start a service inside the BroadcastReceiver but this Service finish when BroadcastReceiver lifecycle completes. I want to keep alive the Serive

Please help me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't provide solution to your 1st question, I'll answer the second one.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleService.class);
    context.getApplicationContext().startService(intent);       
}
```

Also, Android SDK developers [don't recommend](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/seamlessness.html#interrupt) to start activities from broadcast receivers or services.

Comment: thanks, i accepted your answer, its good, now i have no need to start activity

Answer (score 2):

use `context` instead of `this` like this:

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

register your service in the `manifest` file and use `startservice`.

Comment: I use context, but problem same exists

Answer (score 0):

This code worked fine for me

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(Tag, "Start Listening Phone Call");
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    switch (tm.getCallState()) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.v(Tag, "No call");
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.v(Tag, "A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting");
        Intent i = new Intent(context,MyActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
```